# How to ask Unity to "replace" one implementation for test purpose

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

We are using Unity for DI, and at some point, we have a whole initialization process(discover some modules, which are registering their implementation).

I've one class, `CommunicationGate` which is `virtual`. In one of my integration tests, I would like the DI to return not `CommunicationGate` but `CommunicationGateMock` which derives from the original one, and have some virtual method overriden.

Is this possible? How?

Comment: @PJvG: Not sure were to start in fact. Should I derives the whole IUnityContainer ? Is there a specific method to call ? Should I instantiate myself the instance I want to replace or giving another class is enough?

Comment: I've found some articles for you where there are mentions of mock and Unity Container. Maybe you already found them and they were not useful to you, but here they are anyway: 1. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649614.aspx, 2. http://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/momchil-mitev%27s-blog/2014/04/08/unit-tests-using-unity-dependency-injection-in-sitefinity-cms, 3. http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/how-not-to-do-dependency-injection-the-static-or-singleton-container and 4. https://www.thomaslevesque.com/2015/06/14/create-an-auto-mocking-container-with-unity-and-fakeiteasy/.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear how you're setting up your integration test environment, but whether you're in a test assembly, or if you use a configuration switch, you could then just override the registration when you detect you're in integrated testing environment. For example, a really coarse way, to do it :

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{
    UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
    UnityRegistrer.Register(container); // Your proper registrations

    bool isIntegratedTest = Super.Logic(); // Get from config, argument, whatever.

    if (isIntegratedTest)
        UnityRegistrerTest.Register(container);

    RestOfTheProgram();
}

public static class UnityRegistrer
{
    public static void Register(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        container.RegisterType<ICommunicationGate, CommunicationGate>("ImplementationOne");
        container.RegisterType<ICommunicationGate, CommunicationGate>("ImplementationTwo",
            new InjectionConstructor(new InjectionParameter<Whatever>("Blah")));
    }
}

public static class UnityRegistrerTest
{
    public static void Register(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        container.RegisterType<ICommunicationGate, CommunicationGateMock>("ImplementationOne");
    }
}
```

I did use `ICommunicationGate` just to push the agenda of using interfaces for registrations, but you could use a base class. `UnityRegistrerTest` would of course not be in your program class, or even in the same assembly, but my point is more about "You can override a registration for the mocks, and keep some of the other registrations, even if they're on the same class, as long as you're using named registrations with different name."

Edit: Here is how I would do it if you're running integrated tests using a different project :

```
// Same UnityRegistrer class is located in the regular library.

// Same UnityRegistrerTest class, but is located in the test assembly.

// In the actual test class where you want to override the registration
[TestClass]
public class WhateverUnitTest
{
    IUnityContainer container;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestClassInitialization()
    {
        UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
        UnityRegistrer.Register(container);
        UnityRegistrerTest.Register(container);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Blahhhhhh
    {
        //Arrange
        ICommunicationGate communicationGate = container.Resolve<ICommunicationGate>("ImplementationOne");

        //Act
        ...

        //Assert
        ...
    }
}
```